# Angular/Typescript lint error to make "let" as "const"

Tags: angular

In Angular with typescript, how to create a empty array and push the values in it,

```
 @Pipe({name: 'keys'})
    export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
          keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }
        return keys;
      }
    }
```

> let keys - Giving ts lint error

I like to continue with "let" type

Comment: yes, because for each iteration the value of `key` is not changing. In that case, you should use `const`

Comment: set `"prefer-const": false` in tslint config

Comment: @callback: I want to know why we shouldn't use "let" here. and problem "keys" not the "key"

Comment: @Aravind: looking for a direct answers instead of workaround.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, here is why you should use `const` here instead of `let`. `const`, when declaring compound objects, indicates, that the object cannot be reassigned to another reference of an object.

```
const arr = [];
arr = [1,2,3]; // will throw an error!
```

But it does not mean you cannot change the *internal structure* of the object:

```
const arr = [];
arr.push(1) // see, the array internally is changes, it is now [1], but the reference didn't change. so this is completely okay
```

TSLint uses a policy which requires you to use `const` rather then `let` if you have a value that is never being reassigned after its declaration. There are no downsides to this approach. A good point is that someone working on your code later will now that reassigning that array to a new value is a bad idea and that you depend on that array not being reassigned. If you use `let` someone may easily change the array to point to something else, possibly breaking your code. For consistency we always declare such variables with the keyword `const`.

If you really just want to use `let`, workaround was provided in the comments, but I strongly suggest you stick with the standard, as this is not a good idea.

Comment: Exactly!! What I need. Thank you:)